# How to access an array returned from controller to ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a model that returns two queries.

This is the part of the model that it returns

```
$debit_journal_query = $this->db->select('journal_id, date, account, debit, credit')
                                ->from('journal_trans')
                                ->where('journal_id', $debit_journal_id)
                                ->get();       

$credit_journal_query = $this->db->select('journal_id, date, account, debit, credit')
                                ->from('journal_trans')
                                ->where('journal_id', $credit_journal_id)
                                ->get();         

return array('debit' => $debit_journal_query, 'credit' => $credit_journal_query);
```

And this is my controller. I passed the `$data` using json_encode

```
//This method adds a double journal entry to the journal table
public function doubleAddJournal() {
    //Get the values from post
    $date = $this->input->post('date');
    $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
    $debit = $this->input->post('debit');
    $credit = $this->input->post('credit');

    $user = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $data = $this->JournalModel->doubleAddJournal($date, $amount, $debit, $credit, $user);

    echo json_encode(array('data' => $data););
}
```

And this is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    , url: '<?php echo base_url('doubleAddJournal'); ?>'
    , data: { date: date
         , amount: amount
         , debit: debit
         , credit: credit
    }
    , dataType: 'json'
    , success: function(data) {
        $('#journalDoubleAdd').modal('close');

        $(data).each(function() {
            $('#journalLogs').append($('<tr id="'+ this.journal_id +'">'
                + '<td class="dateJournal">'+ this.date +'</td>'
                + '<td class="accountJournal">'+ this.account +'</td>'
                + '<td class="debitJournal">'+ parseFloat(this.debit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
                + '<td class="creditJournald">'+ parseFloat(this.credit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
                + '</tr>'));
            });
        }
    , error: function(errorw) {
            alert('error');
    }
});
```

However I am getting undefined on all values inside the `$(data).each(function(){})`. Where am I getting it wrong? I know that this how you do it when you access only a single query. But how do you do it when you pass multiple query results? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, there is a syntax error in the line json_encode(array('data' => $data);); , change to json_encode(array('data' => $data));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.each()` instead of `$.each()`, so you treat `data` as DOM selectors. Instead of that you should use:

```
$.each(data.data, function (key, value) {
    ('#journalLogs').append($('<tr id="'+ value.journal_id +'">'
       + '<td class="dateJournal">'+ value.date +'</td>'
       + '<td class="accountJournal">'+ value.account +'</td>'
       + '<td class="debitJournal">'+ parseFloat(value.debit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
       + '<td class="creditJournald">'+ parseFloat(value.credit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
       + '</tr>'));
});
```

Check documentation for both of them:

- [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

---

Updated according to the array structure. You need to iterate over first dimension and then after the second, so:

```
$.each(data.data, function (type, typeData) { // type is "credit" or "debit"
    $.each(typeData, function (key, value) {
        ('#journalLogs').append($('<tr id="'+ value.journal_id +'">'
            + '<td class="dateJournal">'+ value.date +'</td>'
            + '<td class="accountJournal">'+ value.account +'</td>'
            + '<td class="debitJournal">'+ parseFloat(value.debit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
            + '<td class="creditJournald">'+ parseFloat(value.credit).toFixed(2) +'</td>'
            + '</tr>'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I get `undefined` values for all. Does that mean that there is something wrong with my query or how I `json_encode(array('data' => $data));`. Should it just be `json_encode($data);`? This is what I have in the Network tab when inspecting the ajax call `{data: {,…}}
data
:
{,…}`

Comment: @CronasDeSe First of all try to `console.log(data);` at the beginning of your `success` callback, to make sure it has proper structure.

Comment: It returns zero rows. I guess there is something wrong with my queries.

Comment: I seem to have forgotten to return the result and just return the query. I changed this `return array('debit' => $debit_journal_query, 'credit' => $credit_journal_query);` to `return array('debit' => $debit_journal_query->result(), 'credit' => $credit_journal_query->result());` I get the correct structure with correct values but I still get undefined when I iterate over them.

Comment: @CronasDeSe So now in response you get `{"data":{"debit":"value","credit":"value"}}`?

Comment: I get `{"data": {"credit": array[0] {"values"}, "debit": array[0] {"values"}}}`

Comment: @CronasDeSe Ok, so there is one more dimension. Could you try to iterate over `data.data.credit` in `$.each()`?

Comment: I tried it and I got the result from my `credit` array. Is it possible to incorporate @james_bond answer above?

Comment: @CronasDeSe So to have all date you can merge the arrays in your model, or make two iteration in success callback (I've edited my answer).

Answer (score 2):

In the php use `json_encode($data);`

In the js use

```
$.each(data, function(i, v){
/* your dom manipulation code*/
});
```

Comment: So should I access for example the `journal_id` using `v.journal_id`. Coz I did this and the same thing happens with what @marian0 suggested. I still get undefined. But I get a different structure from the `console.log` with your answer but I still get correct values.

Comment: v will contain the object, so yes if the object you're expecting has a journal_id property

Comment: However I get undefined values. This is what the structure looks like `{"data": {"credit": array[0] {"values"}, "debit": array[0] {"values"}}}`

Comment: You need to review your php code, and adapt it to the format your js expects it